# cete.DynamicPdf formattedTextArea doesn't render html

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, formatted-text, dynamicpdf

I am trying to create a pdf with text formatting using cete.dynamicpdf and html
I am using the formattedtextarea which supposedly can handle html input.

```
     FontFamily ff = new FontFamily("fontFamily", font);
        FormattedTextAreaStyle style = new FormattedTextAreaStyle(ff, fontSize, true);
        FormattedTextArea textArea = new FormattedTextArea(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(text), x * mmToPoints, y * mmToPoints, w * mmToPoints, h * mmToPoints, style);
```

I am currently passing simple **some text** tags to the "text", but when the documents gets created no bold text is to be seen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to define some fonts for the fontfamily object to get the tags to work

```
    //Building font objects and FontFamily object. 
        TrueTypeFont verdanaRegularFont = new TrueTypeFont("verdana.TTF");
        TrueTypeFont verdanaBoldFont = new TrueTypeFont("verdanab.TTF");
        TrueTypeFont verdanaBoldItalicFont = new TrueTypeFont("verdanaz.TTF");
        TrueTypeFont verdanaItalicFont = new TrueTypeFont("verdanai.TTF");
        FontFamily verdanaFontFamily = new FontFamily("VerdanaFontFamily", verdanaRegularFont, verdanaBoldFont, verdanaItalicFont, verdanaBoldItalicFont); 
        FormattedTextAreaStyle style = new FormattedTextAreaStyle(verdanaFontFamily, fontSize, true);
        FormattedTextArea textArea = new FormattedTextArea(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(text), x * mmToPoints, y * mmToPoints, w * mmToPoints, h * mmToPoints, style);
```